# Работа с object

Tags: c#

У меня есть переменная типа object и с ней производиться математическая операция. Вопрос, как использовать эту переменную как тип, который в ней лежит. Что то вроде этого:

```
object t = 10;
int x = 5;
Console.WriteLine(x + ((t.GetType())t));  // Это почемуто не работает
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dynamic t = 10;

int x = 5;

Console.WriteLine(x + t);
```

Так пойдет?

Comment: Да, это то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

```
object t = 10;
int x = 5;
Console.WriteLine((int)t + x);
```

И не нужен никакой dynamic.

Comment: В моей программе зарание не известно какому типу принадлежит t, поэтому ваш вариант выдаст ошибку если там будет не int значение

Comment: Нужно было это указать в вопросе